# Add key and variable to multidimensional Array based on conditions

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wonder if it's possible to add a key and value to an array, based on certain conditions.
This piece of script makes an api-call to retrieve sportresults from multiple teams based on a teamID number.

```
$length = $numberofTeams
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $teamID             = $objTeamID[$i]['Teamid'];
    $teamResults        = 'http://api.com/teamresults/' . $Teamid;
    $dataResults        = file_get_contents($teamResults);
    $objResults[]   = json_decode($dataResults, true);
}
```

The result is an array with this structure:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [errorcode] => 9995 
            [message] => No results
     ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [errorcode] => 1000 
            [message] => Ok, Schedule follows 
            [List] => Array ( 
                        [0] => Array ( 
                            [MatchID] => 7683403 
                            [Number] => 630 
                            [Result] => 2 - 1 
                            [Datum] => 2013-08-27 
                            [Tijd] => 2000 
                            [CompType] => B )
                        [1] => Array ( 
                            [MatchID] => 7683403 
                            [Number] => 630 
                            [Result] => 4 - 0                               [Datum] => 2013-08-27 
                            [Tijd] => 2000 
                            [CompType] => B ) 
                            )
                ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
    [errorcode] => 9995 
    [message] => No results )
)
```

Before saving it in an MySql database, for later use I need to add the teamID-variable to every result so it would become:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [errorcode] => 9995 
            [message] => No results
     ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [errorcode] => 1000 
            [message] => Ok, Schedule follows 
            [List] => Array ( 
                        [0] => Array ( 
                            [teamID] => 'value from $teamID'
                            [MatchID] => 7683403 
                            [Number] => 630 
                            [Result] => 2 - 1
                            [Datum] => 2013-08-27 
                            [Tijd] => 2000 
                            [CompType] => B )
                        [1] => Array ( 
                            [teamID] => 'value from $teamID'                                [MatchID] => 7683403 
                            [Number] => 630 
                            [Result] => 4 - 0
                            [Datum] => 2013-08-27 
                            [Tijd] => 2000 
                            [CompType] => B ) 
                            )
                ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
    [errorcode] => 9995 
    [message] => No results )
)
```

The length of the array varies and also the number of results vary. I have no influence on the result of the api-call itself, because it's been set up by big sport association.

I'm absolutely no programmer, so I'm out of my depth her, but this is a voluntary job for an amateur sportsclub so hiring a programmer is no option.

Rgds, Bonzyx

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($objResults[1]['List'])){
    foreach($objResults[1]['List'] as &$listItem){
        $listItem['teamID'] = $teamID;
    }
    unset($listItem); //good practice to unset this reference to last array element
}
```

You could do the same with php's [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function, but since you said you're not a programmer I think the foreach method is more clear to you.